# Watir can't locate an element with xpath

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, xpath, watir

I got this html (It's simplified to see the deep)

```
<html>
    <frameset>
        <frame>
            #document
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <div>
                            <form>
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input :) >
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
        </frame>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

And when i run this commands i get the following:

`@browser.element(:xpath => "/html").exists?` => TRUE

`@browser.element(:xpath => "/html/frameset").exists?` => TRUE

`@browser.element(:xpath => "/html/frameset/frame").exists?` => TRUE

`@browser.element(:xpath => "/html/frameset/frame/html").exists?` => FALSE

The `#document` apparently is hiding the rest since after that, the rest is FALSE.
I tried to get the Xpath with Chrome by left click on the code but i get the "inner code" like from the second `html` and not from the first.

**Question**

How can i access the input of that code?

*If i run `@browser.frame.text.include? Something` where the "Something" is inside the table, it returns TRUE.

Comment: Hello, if this site is hosted on internet then it would  be better if you share the URL and exact element that you are trying to locate. Because suggestion provided on the basis of above might or might not work for you.

Comment: Try starting from `//frameset/frame`.  Also do the framesets have any ID's you could use ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The site is hosted on the internet but you can access  to it directly with the UR :( ; There is no ID to use :( ; Will try your suggestion when i can ;)

Comment: I Googled for "Selenium inner frame" and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464808/how-to-navigate-a-subframe-inside-a-frameset-using-selenium-webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem arises because a frame is a holder for a complete html document inside the one initially connected to.

Try setting a variable to the frame itself:

```
target_frame = @browser.element(:xpath => "/html/frameset/frame")
```

And then you should be able to see the document inside the frame:

```
frame_html = target_frame.html
```

I'm winging this off the top of my head but I think it is in the ballpark (sorry about the scrambled metaphors...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have time to try this at the moment but i will when i can.